# JasperReports 6.3. Get 'Class com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory not found' error for plsql language used at queryString

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Trying to upgrade reports from *JasperReports 3.5.3* to *6.3.1*.

The snippet from *jrxml*:

```
<queryString language = "plsql"> <![CDATA[{call RPT_OCP($P{CUR},$P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR})}]]> </queryString>
```

While trying to compile the report, facing the following exception,

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory not found.
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1255)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:695)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:881)
     [java]     ... 37 more
```

The *JasperReports* of 6.3.1 version does not have any *jasperreport-extentions jar*, what would be the work around for this?

Comment: Looks like the class is not longer available in this Version. You have to Change to an other SQLQueryExecuterFactory

Comment: Clean your project / Maven clean and try once

Comment: @KomalGoyal You should post the *jrxml*

Comment: @Alex K Following is the snippet <queryString language = "plsql">
  <![CDATA[{call RPT_OCP($P{CUR},$P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR})}]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: If I remove the language attribute from queryString tag, it gives an error for ORACLE_REF_CURSOR parameter                                           
[java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem generating report: Report design not valid : 
     [java]   1. Parameter type not supported in query : ORACLE_REF_CURSOR class java.sql.ResultSet   Parameter defined in JRXML as                                                                                     <parameter name="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" class="java.sql.ResultSet" isForPrompting="false"/>

Comment: @PRATHAPS have cleaned the project a couple of times, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Jens , Could you pass me some SELQueryExecutorFactory api link..

Comment: @KomalGoyal in this Moment i see tha package is wrong: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory the doc you can fine [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory.html)

Comment: @KomalGoyal Where did you get this error? At Studio or at your Java application?

Comment: @AlexK, I am getting this error in my Java application

Comment: It is compiling well for my sample. Check your *jasperreports.properties* file. Do you have `net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.plsql=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory` at this flie?

Comment: @AlexK yes that is what was different.. thanks Alex.

Comment: How can I mark this question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that the handler (*Executer*) for ***plsql*** language is defined at *jasperreports.properties* file.

The right definition (for *6.x* version) is:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.plsql=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory
```

Maybe you have something different since the previous version of *JasperReports* engine.

BTW, *JasperReports 3.5.3* did not support this extenstion (*plsql*). I think that using *com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory* at your case was some kind of stub/fix.

Comment: Thank you a ton. :)